# How to get div id in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp.net

I want to click li with click property.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled clearfix">
    <li style="float: left; width: 33.33333%; padding: 5px;" onclick="maviTema()">
</ul>
```

And after I will run maviTema function in javascript.This javascript code changes my panel heading color.How can I do?

```
function maviTema() {
  var div = document.getElementById('baslikBilgi');           
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'green'; 
}
```

I want to set back color id="baslikbilgi":

```
<div class="bg-blue-active" id="baslikBilgi">Başlık Bilgileri</div>
```

Comment: What is wrong with the code you posted?

Comment: it doesn't work.I don't get error.

Comment: This code seems fine. You could do `background = 'green'` instead of `backgroundColor = 'green'` but afaik your code should just work.

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work again.

Comment: When debugging you should not be using the phrase "it didn't work". You should always be more specific like "The event handler didn't fire" or something like that. "It doesn't work" is a useless statement.

Comment: make sure java-script is enable in your browser setting. and put this function code in `<script>` tag @EmreAslan

Comment: @UmangPatwa enable javascript.I think that li does not work because it is in ul.

Comment: @EmreAslan have you tried my answer?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey Yes I tried.

Comment: Working or not?

Comment: @AbhishekPandey  this is li into ul.

Comment: No doesn't working

Comment: What do you exactly want? Can you please elaborate more?

Comment: @EmreAslan i try it in `<ul>` and it working use `debugger;` in your function and then check it will give you exact error

Comment: Did you write the js code after the div?

Comment: No I wrote into head tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you want to trigger function with click, you can just call it right after your function.

```js
function maviTema() {
  var div = document.getElementById('baslikBilgi');
  div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';
}
maviTema();
```

```html
<div class="bg-blue-active" id="baslikBilgi">Başlık Bilgileri</div>
```

> Or if setting bg-color is only need of this function, then you can try
>   simple code instead

```
document.getElementById('baslikBilgi').style.background='green'
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure entirely what your question is as you have seemed to have answered it in your post. To change the background color of an element using vanilla JS all you need to do is set the `backgroundColor` property like so:

`document.getElementById('baslikBilgi').style.backgroundColor='#0f0'`

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="bg-blue-active" id="baslikBilgi">Başlık Bilgileri</div>

<li style="float: left; width: 33.33333%; padding: 5px;" onclick="maviTema()">Link</li>

<script>
function maviTema() {
            var div = document.getElementById('baslikBilgi');
                div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

        }
</script>
```

When I have this code on my index.html/index.php file and I click the 'li' it works fine for me!

Make sure you have your Javascript code in a script tag ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
 
   function maviTema() {
        var div = document.getElementById('baslikBilgi');           
            div.style.background = 'green';

    }
```

```html
<ul class="list-unstyled clearfix"> 

    <li style="float: left; width: 33.33333%; padding: 5px;"onclick="maviTema()">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-skin="skin-blue" style="display: block; box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)" class="clearfix full-opacity-hover"> </a>
     <p class="text-center no-margin">Mavi</p> 
    </li>
    </ul>

<div class="bg-blue-active" id="baslikBilgi">Başlık Bilgileri</div>
```

Try This,

```
   <ul class="list-unstyled clearfix"> 

    <li style="float: left; width: 33.33333%; padding: 5px;"onclick="maviTema()">
    <a href="javascript:void(0);" data-skin="skin-blue" style="display: block; box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)" class="clearfix full-opacity-hover"> </a>
     <p class="text-center no-margin">Mavi</p> 
    </li>
    </ul>
 <script>
    function maviTema() {
        var div = document.getElementById('baslikBilgi');           
            div.style.background = 'green';

    } 
</script>
<div class="bg-blue-active" id="baslikBilgi">Başlık Bilgileri</div>
```

Comment: <ul class="list-unstyled clearfix">
                            <li style="float: left; width: 33.33333%; padding: 5px;" onclick="maviTema()"><a href="javascript:void(0);" data-skin="skin-blue" style="display: block; box-shadow: 0 0 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.4)" class="clearfix full-opacity-hover">                               
                            
                            </a>
                                <p class="text-center no-margin">Mavi</p>
                            </li></ul>

Comment: My li into "UL"

Answer (score 0):

Your Code works fine.
Make sure you have the script tags
If you are importing another js files into your page in the footer try to move your script above them or try to run it from the header, and it Will work fine

```
<script>

 function maviTema() {
 var div = document.getElementById('baslikBilgi');
            div.style.backgroundColor = 'green';

        }
</script>
```